# Animate js

Tags: jquery, css, javascript

```
    $(".prew").live("click",function(){
        var a = $(".uislider").css('margin-top');
        var b = $(".uislider").height();
        var e= parseInt(a, 10);
        if (e!=0)
        {
        e=e+246;
            if (e<b)
            {   
                $(".uislider").stop(true, true).animate({'margin-top': e+'px'},600);
            }
        }
    });
    $(".next").live("click",function(){
        var a = $(".uislider").css('margin-top');
        var b = $(".uislider").height();
        var e = parseInt(a, 10);
        b='-'+b;
        e=e-246;
        if (e>b)
        {
            $(".uislider").stop(true, true).animate({'margin-top': e+'px'},600);
        }
    });
```

В общем делаю простенький не нагружающий слайдер, но есть проблема, работает хорошо если не нажимать очень быстро, тогда сбивается слайдер и вылетает за пределы условия if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После нажатия устанавливайте переменную которая запрещает нажатие пока не будет удалена, и удаляйте её после завершения анимации (callback).

---

```
var click = false;
$(".next").live("click", function() {
    if ( click ) return false;
    click = true;
    $(".uislider").animate({'margin-top': '50px'}, 600, function() { 
        click = false;
    });
});
```

[**Пример.**](http://jsfiddle.net/b6c3x/)

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант проще:
     $(".uislider").animate({'margin-top': '50px'}, {queue: false}, 600)

Здесь обратите внимание на параметр queue: false и отсутствие метода stop().
Я понимаю так, что stop в принципе включен для предотвращения выстраивания очередей действий при многократном быстром нажатии. Это не очень хорошо как раз из-за возможности описанных вами побочных эффектов.
queue: false — штатный документированный способ избавиться от нежелательных эффектов.